# (When) Is the category of descent data equivalent to the essential image of the base change?

Tags: category-theory, descent

Consider a family of continuous maps $(U_i\to U)$. For a family of bundles $(X_i\to U_i)$, TFAE:

- The family is a pullback of a single bundle $X\to U$;
- There exist transition isomorphisms satisfying the cocycle condition.

Thus, for topological spaces, existence of descent data for a fixed object is equivalent to the object being in the essential image of the familial pullback $\mathsf C_{/U}\to \prod_i\mathsf C_{/U_i}$.

I am wondering whether and when the *category* of descent data is actually equivalent to the essential image of this familial pullback functor.

More generally, consider a pseudofunctor $F:\mathsf C^\text{op}\to \mathsf{Cat}$. Given a family of arrows $(U_i\to U)$, define the category $\mathsf{Desc}(F,(U_i\to U))$ of descent data as the 2-limit of the diagram below, where the arrows are familial pullback functors and $U_{ij},U_{ijk}$ are the obvious multi-pullbacks. $$\prod_iF(U_i)\rightrightarrows\prod_{ij}F(U_{ij})\substack{\longrightarrow\\[-1em] \longrightarrow \\[-1em] \longrightarrow} \prod_{ijk}F(U_{ijk})$$

When is there a canonical equivalence between the essential image of the familial pullback $F(U)\to \prod_iF(U_i)$ and the category of descent data for $F$ along $(U_i\to U)$ and how to prove it?

**Remark.** Note I am not asking when the category of descent data is equivalent to the domain of the familial base change. I am hoping for much much weaker conditions than the family $(U_i\to U)$ being of effective descent.

Comment: I'm confused : why do you want to compare the category of descent data with a full subcategory of $\prod_i F(U_i)$ ? Descent data are meant to compare "a structured object of $\prod_i F(U_i)$" with $F(U)$. And if descent hold, then the category of descend data is equivalent to the category $F(U)$, which is different from $\prod_i F(U_i)$.

Comment: There is an obvious functor $\operatorname{Desc}(F(\{U_i\rightarrow U\}))\rightarrow\prod_i F(U_i)$. In some cases it is essentially surjective (think of Galois descent of vector spaces) but it is almost never full.

Comment: @Roland ahh, what gave me trouble was a harmful analogy. In the case of continuous functions, coherence of a family is a *property*. On the other hand, descent data for a family of bundles is a *structure*. Even though the existence of a descent datum for a family of bundles is equivalent to being in the essential image of the familial base-change, the category of descent data has chosen descent data as objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be an answer, but definitively too long for a comment.

The way I understand descent theory is the following : if you have a cover $\{U_i\rightarrow U\}$ and objects $(X_i)$ on the $(U_i)$ then the question is not "Does the family $(X_i)$ comes from an $X$ on $U$", but rather "Do I have something on $(X_i)$ making it an object on $U$". And the answer may be

- Oh yeah, I do have a Galois action compatible with the structure map...
- Oh yeah, I do have isomorphisms on overlaps $U_i\cap U_j$  such that ...

In other words, you have a functor $F(U)\rightarrow\prod F(U_i)$ which factors as 
$$ F(U)\rightarrow\operatorname{Desc}(F,\{U_i\rightarrow U\})\rightarrow\prod F(U_i)$$
and you start with a family $(X_i)\in\prod F(U_i)$. Then there are two different problems :

- Does it have a descent data ? This is a condition : the functor $\operatorname{Desc}(F,\{U_i\rightarrow U\})\rightarrow\prod F(U_i)$ might not be essentially surjective.
- Choose a descent data ! This is a structure ! The family $(X_i)$ might come from different $X$ on $U$. And the functor $\operatorname{Desc}(F,\{U_i\rightarrow U\})\rightarrow\prod F(U_i)$ might not be full.

So you seem to be interested on the first point only. But I don't think the object satisfying this condition might organized in a interesting category (other that the full category of $(X_i)$ which have a descent data). In other words, if you consider only families $(X_i)$ which has isomorphisms $X_i|_{U_{ij}}\simeq X_j|_{U_{ij}}$ satisfying a condition, what morphisms do you want between to such families if you don't specify these isomorphisms (this extra-structure) ?

You ask about the essential image of $F(U)\rightarrow\prod F(U_i)$, but not necessarily the full essential image. I just don't know what it means. The image of a functor is not a category in general.

Let's have a look at an example where descent hold so we can safely replace $\operatorname{Desc}(F,\{U_i\rightarrow U\})$ by $F(U)$.

Galois descent of vector spaces. If $L/k$ is a (Galois) extension, the functor $F(k)\rightarrow F(L)$ is essentially surjective : every $L$ vector space has a $k$-structure. The whole point is the extra-structure. Now take two $\mathbb{C}$-vector $V,W$ spaces of dimension 2. What morphisms do you want to consider between them so that you can say : "they are morphisms between two $\mathbb{R}$-structure on them" ?

Do you want to consider all morphism ? Because after all, for all morphism $f:V\rightarrow W$ there are Galois semi-linear action on $V$ and $W$ making $f$ equivariant. In that case, your image category will be the full $F(L)$ but this is not equivalent to $F(k)=\operatorname{Desc}(F,L/k)$.

Or do you want to consider only equivariant morphism after choosing for every vector space a specific Galois semi-linear action ? That does not seem very canonical, and worse : the functor $F(k)=\operatorname{Desc}(F,L/k)\rightarrow F(L)$ does not factor through this "image" anymore.

Comment: Just a remark regarding the third paragraph since I have not yet read your entire answer: I am asking about the essential image of $F(U)\to \prod_iF(U_i)$, not $\operatorname{Desc}(F,\{U_i\rightarrow U\})\rightarrow\prod F(U_i)$. Also, what is the "full essential image" of a functor?

Comment: @Arrow Ok I'll change that, but it does not change anything for categories where descent hold. What I meant by "full essential image" was in response to your comment : this is the full sub category of objects isomorphic to an $F(X)$ if $F$ is the functor. This is usually called the essential image, but in your comment you said that the essential image needs not be a full subcategory...

Answer (score 0):

What confused me was a harmful analogy. In the case of continuous functions, coherence of a family is a *property* of the family. On the other hand, descent data for a family of bundles is a *structure* with a coherence property. Even though the existence of a descent datum for a family of bundles is equivalent to being in the essential image of the familial base-change, the category of descent data has chosen descent data as objects. Hence it is unreasonable to expect equivalence with the essential image.